# Subclass viewController in storyboard and programmatically change UI from subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

What I'm basically trying to do is have a storyboard with a navController and a couple views which are set up programmatically - or at least have subviews that are added programatically. So I've set up an example workspace, I have a navController and 2 viewControllers that are pushed depending on which button is pressed.

Here's the storyboard:
[image]

As you can see, the viewController on the bottom has it's class set to `CVViewController`. In `CVViewController`, I have my `viewDidLoad` as

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIView *redColor = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.window.frame];
    redColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [self.view addSubview:redColor];
}
```

But then when I segue into this view on the simulator, there's no red background that should be there (because I added it programmatically).

So I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I basically just want to be a able to configure a storyboard viewController programmatically from a custom class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
UIView *redColor = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.window.frame];
```

to this:

```
UIView *redColor = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```